# input file - Select multiple files, but each file in an input file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, input

I know that to select multiple files in the file selection box it is enough to use the "multiple" attribute in the input file like this...

```
<input type="file" name="img" multiple>
```

[Ref.: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_multiple.asp ]

**QUESTION:**

I am looking for a way to select multiple files in the file selection box but in such a way that **each file results in an input file**. It's possible? If so, how?

Thanks! **=D**

Comment: No that's not possible. It's possible to enumerate the files in a multiple file input, and you can create new single file inputs from that, however you cannot set the value of those inputs. This seems like an X/Y question; if you already have a multiple file control, why do you need single ones?

Comment: I am using a tool that accepts only one file per input file, although it allows multiple input files.